# Python: Function call into another function, possible problems with scopes?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, montecarlo

**The Problem**:
(Edited version)
Everytime I do the for loops in select_jump(jump_catalog, atom_lattice) the function is using the currently produced lattice for the next jump. I want it to use the lattice/atom_lattice which is originally passed to select_jump(). I already tried a "dummy" variable/container to "save" the original lattice to another variable and continue working with the new one but somehow the change is happening to all lattices/arrays.

-> I think it has sth to do with envirnments and scopes and that the two functions are happening on the same scope therefore using the same variable and not generating a new scope with a new variable but I am not sure. Could somebody help me wit this? further down I provided example arrays for the code. It also shows what I get and what I want to get. (Look at fused[0][8] at each of these arrays provided down there)

```
def move_atom(lattice,a,b, dir):
    lattice_B = lattice
    lattice_B[a][b] = 0
    if dir == 'r' or dir == 0:
        lattice_B[a][b+1] = 1
    if dir == 'l' or dir ==1:
        lattice_B[a][b-1] = 1
    if dir == 'd' or dir ==2:
        lattice_B[a+1][b] = 1
    if dir == 'u' or dir == 3:
        lattice_B[a-1][b] = 1
    return lattice_B

def select_jump(jump_catalog, atom_lattice):
    testcontainer = atom_lattice
    catalog_of_catalogs = np.zeros([np.count_nonzero(jump_catalog), np.shape(jump_catalog)[0],np.shape(jump_catalog)[1],np.shape(jump_catalog)[2]])
    chosen_atoms_indices = np.nonzero(jump_catalog)

    for i in range(len(chosen_atoms_indices[0])):
        print(chosen_atoms_indices[0][i],chosen_atoms_indices[1][i],chosen_atoms_indices[2][i])
        tst = move_atom(testcontainer,chosen_atoms_indices[0][i],chosen_atoms_indices[1][i],chosen_atoms_indices[2][i])
        print(tst)


    return catalog_of_catalogs

if __name__ == "__main__":
    a=select_jump(jc1,fused)
```

Lattice/atom-lattice arrays

```
fused =
[ [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ],
  [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
  [ 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
  [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
  [ 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
  [ 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
  [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
  [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
  [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
  [ 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ] ]
```

What I want to get (one example of many look at fused[0][9] in comparison to fused[0][8]:

```
fused =
[ [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ],
  [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
  [ 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
  [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
  [ 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
  [ 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
  [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
  [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
  [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
  [ 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ] ]
```

Comment: Can you make this example *more minimal*? Reduce that wall of text to a concise explanation, remove code that isn't necessary to demonstrate the problematic behaviour.

Comment: `testcontainer = atom_lattice` does not create a copy of the `atom_lattice` `list`. More importantly, `lattice_B = lattice` does not create a copy of `lattice` so you are just using the same `list` throughout your loop.

Comment: @deceze ok I have reduced it but I am not sure if one can understand the problem then.

Comment: @Axe319 that is what I gathered but how do I get the function to produce a new object/numpy array? I thought in python variables can be just copied like that.

Comment: Solved with numpy.copy()

Comment: @AlLex Assignment never copies. This is a good read if you haven't seen it yet https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html